# Combining rows when data from two columns are the same between columns but not within the columns in R

Tags: r

I have an excel file with multiple rows and columns. The last column gives some value. What I want to do is - find the rows with same column details between the first two columns except the last one and sum their last column value. For example: if input is

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ABC     | DEF     | 9       |       5 |
| XYZ     | PQR     | 4       |       4 |
| DEF     | ABC     | 2       |      11 |
| Test1   | Test2   | 1       |      12 |
| PQR     | XYZ     | 3       |      54 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
then output should be

+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ABC     | DEF     | 11      |      16 |
| PQR     | XYZ     | 7       |      58 |
| Test1   | Test2   | 1       |      12 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
How this can be acheived in R?
```

Comment: This is not clear. It seems that the order of entries in `Column1` and `Column2` does not matter to you. What are the rules for ordering entries in `Column1` and `Column2` in the final output? What do you do if entries in `Column3` are different?

Comment: That's correct. The order of entries in Column1 and Column 2 does not matter. Column4 entries should be combined based on Column1 and Column2, regardless of what is in Column3.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What are the **rules** for ordering entries in `Column1` and `Column2`? What is the **rule** for selecting entries in `Column3` if they are not the same!

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I want to order entries in Column1 and Column2 alphabetically. I have made an edit to my question. The contents of Column3 should also be summed.

Comment: Still not clear. In your second line of the final output `Column1=XYZ` and `Column2=PQR` are obviously *not* alphabetically sorted (if it had been sorted, it would be `Column1=PQR Column2=XYZ`). That aside, I have added a solution that reproduces your expected output where I list the assumptions I make.

Comment: You clearly understand my problem better than I do. How would you only keep the Column1/Column2 combination that is alphabetized?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the logic rules behind your expected output are not very clear.

I assume for the final output that

1. only the first `Column1`/`Column2` combination is kept, and
2. only the first `Column3` entry is kept if entries are different for the same `Column1`/`Column2` combinations.

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate`:

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
 ABC      DEF      GHI            5
 XYZ      PQR      LMN            4
 DEF      ABC      GHI           11
 Test1    Test2    Test3         12
 PQR      XYZ      LMN           54", header = T)

id <- apply(df[, 1:2], 1, function(x)
    paste0(sort(as.character(x)), collapse = "_"))
cbind.data.frame(
    df[!duplicated(id), -4],
    Column4 = aggregate(df$Column4, list(id), sum)[[2]]);
#  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#1     ABC     DEF     GHI      16
#2     XYZ     PQR     LMN      58
#4   Test1   Test2   Test3      12
```

---

### Update

With your new data and revised rules

1. The order of entries `Column1`/`Column2` does not matter; keep combination that is alphabetically sorted.
2. Aggregate by `Column3` and `Column4`.

Base R solution:

```
df <-read.table(text =
    "Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
 ABC      DEF      9              5
 XYZ      PQR      4              4
 DEF      ABC      2             11
 Test1    Test2    1             12
 PQR      XYZ      3             54", header = T)


id <- apply(df[, 1:2], 1, function(x)
    paste0(sort(as.character(x)), collapse = "_")) 
cbind.data.frame(
    setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(unique(id), "_"))), c("Column1", "Column2")),
    aggregate(df[, 3:4], list(id), sum)[, 2:3]);
#  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
#1     ABC     DEF      11      16
#2     PQR     XYZ       7      58
#3   Test1   Test2       1      12
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and patience! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: You're very welcome @BrittneyNguyen; please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the solution.